# Do I need to purchase a license for fonts that come with Adobe software?

Tags: font-licensing

I'm new to graphic design and the more I read about licensed fonts, the more confused I get. I've understood about downloading fonts from the internet, but my question is about the fonts that come up with Microsoft/Windows and Adobe CS5 upon buying the software and installing it on my computer.

Since I bought the software, does this mean I am allowed to use the fonts provided there for designing brochures, posters, logo, book cover etc. and give the design to a client? Or does the client have to purchase a license for these fonts? Some are really expensive like if it's from Adobe. What about the fonts almost everyone with a computer has like Arial, Times New Roman, Courier etc. Do we need license for these?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You may use the fonts which are installed by Adobe applications in anything you design. The license permits their commercial use.

You may **not** give any of the fonts away. There's little reason your clients should need the fonts, but if they do, they are expected to purchase their own license for the fonts.

All this is explained in the Adobe End User License Agreement. If you are concerned about issues, you may want to read that document. Which is also installed with the software.

Comment: As Android does not provide Times New Roman internally for app development, can I still download the font and use it in my app?

Answer (score -1):

Most of the fonts are free. But some are proprietary fonts,  The best option is google fonts, just go to https://www.google.com/fonts and make your own collection. Click on download icon present on right, a modal window will appear,  then click the link present in the line **"Download the font families in your Collection as a .zip file"** and install on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

If the fonts become installed on your OS and the font menu of your programs then you may use them to produce works.  The internal fonts that are nonetheless distributed in public folders of programs may not be licensed: http://www.adobe.com/products/type/font-licensing/restricted-fonts.html.